# Volume using cross sections 21

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

A solid has a circular base of radius 4cm. Find the volume of the solid if every plane section perpendicular to the x-axis is a square. I'm having trouble setting the integral up. 0 to 8 integral pir^2 dx??

Answer (score 1):

We will be integrating with respect to $x$, from the leftmost value of $x$, which is $-4$, to the rightmost value, which is $4$. The volume is
$$\int_{x=-4}^4 A(x)\,dx,$$
where $A(x)$ is the area of cross-section at $x$.

The cross-section is a square. Let us find its side.
Note that the circle has equation $x^2+y^2=16$.

At $x$, the cross-section extends from $y=-\sqrt{16-x^2}$ to $y=\sqrt{16-x^2}$. So the square has side $2\sqrt{16-x^2}$, and therefore $A(x)=4(16-x^2)$.

The rest is straightforward integration. I would prefer to use symmetry, and instead of integrating from $-4$ to $4$, integrate from $0$ to $4$ and double the answer.

**Remark:** To begin, we need to visualize the solid. The base is circular. Imagine the thing sitting on a table. The bottom is a circle. The solid extends upwards, and is "tall" near $x=0$, and tapers off to height near $0$ when $x$ gets close to $-4$ and $4$.  Kind of like a hill, except that there are vertical cliffs on the north and south side.

Comment: Nice one!!. Bit tough to visualize initially.

Comment: @satishramanathan Visualizing these cross section problems is typically the hardest part. A three dimensional sketch can help.